How to Apply Different Logic Based on Source File in React Component?
I'm working on a React application and have a scenario where I need to apply different logic based on the file that calls my component. Here's the setup:
hello-world.js:
if (parsedData.extras?.length > 0) {
    openCheckoutStep('extras'); // it goes to AbcDef.tsx file or AbcDefView component
}

AbcDef.tsx (This file has the route: extras set in it)
export const AbcDefView = () => {
    if (/* condition to check if called from hello-world.js */) {
        // Logic A should be applied
    } else if (/* condition to check if called from GhiJkl.tsx */) {
        // Logic B should be applied
    }
};

GhiJkl.tsx
if (extras.length > 0) {
    navigate('/checkout/extras');
}

I need AbcDefView to apply Logic A if it's called from hello-world.js and Logic B if it's called from GhiJkl.tsx. How can I determine the source of the call in AbcDefView to apply the correct logic?

Can you pass a parameter into the function?

@NicholasTower Yes, we can pass a parameter into the function.

Ok, then that's my recommendation. For example, export const AbcDefView = (isFromHelloWorld) => { if (isFromHelloWorld) { /* Logic A*/ } else { /* Logic B */ }. To be called like AbcDefView(true) if you're in hello-world.js. Does that suffice?

@NicholasTower
Based on that, what changes I need to make in hello-world.js file ?

Instead of calling AbcDefView(), call AbcDefView(true)

I've assumed it's a regular function. If it's a component, then you'll use a prop. <AbcDefView someProp={true} />

Can you explain me through an answer? Its getting complicated in comments.

There isn't a way to tell what source code file a call stack originated in, but you can pass a parameter in to the function to tell it what to do. For example, if there's just two options, you can pass a boolean in:
export const AbcDefView = (isFromHelloWorld) => {
    if (isFromHelloWorld) {
        // Logic A should be applied
    } else {
        // Logic B should be applied
    }
};

In helloWorld.ts, you'll call it like:
AbcDefView(true);

In ghijkl.tsx, you'll call it like:
AbcDefView(false);

If AbcDefView is a react component, you'll use a prop.
export const AbcDefView = ({ isFromHelloWorld }) => {
  // ...
}
// used like:
<AbcDefView isFromHelloWorld={true} />

